# Force sql server to stop caching subquery

Tags: sql-server, caching

I was trying to insert dummy data in database for testing purpose and to match relationship I need to update all id's of one table according to the values of another .

The query I am trying to execute is

```
update LG set BatchID=(SELECT TOP 1 BatchID FROM Batch
ORDER BY NEWID())
```

but BatchID of LG is filled with only one value seems its caching results of inner query ,how to force it not to do caching of subqueries.

Comment: The subquery is executed only once in this query because there is no correlation between the updated table and the subquery.  You'll need to use a different construct.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried with inner query `SELECT TOP 1 BatchID FROM Batch where LG.BatchID != Batch.BatchID ORDER BY NEWID()` but still all rows are updated with same value.

Comment: `update LG set BatchID=t2.BatchID FROM LG inner join batch t2 on t2.?? = LG.??`

Comment: @artm joining of tables LG and Batch won't help because the values aren't same they were generated randomly and separately

Comment: @Shubanker if there's no correlation then `update LG set BatchID=t2.BatchID FROM LG inner join batch t2 on 1=1`

Comment: @artm all the rows of lg is updated by 1st row of batch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) and [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)() to make tables *correlated*

```
;WITH LG_cte AS (
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM LG
), Batch_cte AS (
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as rn
FROM Batch
)

MERGE LG_cte as lg
USING Batch_cte as b
ON lg.rn = b.rn
WHEN MATCHED THEN   
    UPDATE SET BatchID = b.BatchID;
```

F.e. I got this tables:

```
CREATE TABLE LG (
    BatchID int,
    SomeString nvarchar(max)
)
CREATE TABLE Batch (
    BatchID int,
    SomeString1 nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO LG VALUES
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'d')

INSERT INTO Batch VALUES
(7,'e'),
(8,'f'),
(9,'g'),
(10,'h')
```

After running the merge above I will get:

```
BatchID SomeString
7       a
8       b
9       c
10      d
```

In `LG` table

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
update table1 set id = (select newid())
```

If there is caching of newid() then you can use rand()

Comment: the answer seems to be irrelevant